# In the WSO2 Stream Processor, Detecting Anomaly tutorial throws an exception

Tags: wso2, outliers, siddhi, stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I'm trying to replicate the "Detecting Anomalies" tutorial given in the WSO2 stream processor documentation.

```
@App:name('SugarSyrupOutlierPredictionApp')

@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://localhost:5007/SugarSyrupEP', @map(type = 'json'))
define stream SugarSyrupDataStream (viscosity double, temperature double, density double);

@sink(type='log', prefix='Outlier detected in sugar syrup supply:')
define stream OutlierStream (viscosity double, temperature double, density double, outlier bool);

from SugarSyrupDataStream#timeseries:outlier(5, viscosity, temperature, density)
select *
insert into OutlierStream;
```

The error i'm getting at the line, in which i'm calling my outlier function is this.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.SiddhiAppCreationException: Outlier Function is available only for simple linear regression at org.wso2.extension.siddhi.execution.timeseries.LinearRegressionOutlierStreamProcessor.init(LinearRegressionOutlierStreamProcessor.java:221)
```

Am I missing something here or should I be using some other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the extension is only accepting 3 parameters. Please refer [siddhi-execution-timeseries documentation#outlier](https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-execution-timeseries/api/4.1.2/#outlier-stream-processor).

You need to update the tutorial sample to have the range, Y and X as the parameters for the outlier extension. This is because the extension only supports simple linear regressions.

```
@App:name('SugarSyrupOutlierPredictionApp')

@source(type='http', receiver.url='http://localhost:5007/SugarSyrupEP', @map(type = 'json'))
define stream SugarSyrupDataStream (viscosity double, temperature double, density double);

@sink(type='log', prefix='Outlier detected in sugar syrup supply:')
define stream OutlierStream (viscosity double, temperature double, outlier bool);

from SugarSyrupDataStream#timeseries:outlier(5, viscosity, temperature)
select viscosity, temperature, outlier
insert into OutlierStream;
```

Comment: @Dilip Sundar before editing somebody's answer let them know in a comment that there's some issue, but you fixed it using *{your changes}*